# i am trying to select "description" from a rss feed if the title is equal to something

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt

i am trying to select  "description" from a rss feed if the title is equal to something.

in code i have this :

```
public static XmlDocument GetDefaultHoroscopesFeed(string StarSign){
 xdoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("rss/channel/item/[title = '{0}']/description", StarSign));
            xdoc.LoadXml(DefaultPageHoroscopeNode.InnerXml);
            return xdoc;

}
```

but i keep getting this error : Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

Please help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not specifying a node name inbetween `.../item/` and `[title = ...`, therefore you won't get back a valid node-set. Also, in RSS, the `<title>` node will not have a child node called `<description>`.

You need to change your XPath

```
"rss/channel/item/[title = '{0}']/description"
```

into

```
"rss/channel/item[title = '{0}']/description"
```

This will get you the `<item>` node that has a `<title>` node with the value StarSign and then retrieve its `<description>` node.

You could also do this using an `XDocument` and Linq to XML, like so:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathToRss);
XElement description = xdoc.Descendants("item")
    .Where(i => i.Element("title").Value.Equals(StarSign))
    .Select(i => i.Element("description"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```